# scipy.optimize.least_squares - limit number of jacobian evaluations

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares

I am trying to use scipy.optimize.least_squares(fun= my_fun, jac=my_jac, max_nfev= 1000) with two callable functions: my_fun and my_jac

both fuctions: my_fun and my_jac, use an external software to evaluate their value, this task is much time consuming, therefore I prefer to control the number of evaluations for both

the trf method uses the my_fun function for evaluating if trust region is adequate and the my_jac function for determine both the cost function and the jacobian matrix

There is an input parameter max_nfev. does this parameter count only for the fun evaluations? does it consider also the jac evaluations?

moreover, in matlab there are two parameters for the lsqnonlin function, MaxIterations  and MaxFunctionEvaluations. does it exist in scipy.optimize.least_squares?

Thanks
Alon

Answer (score 0):

According to the help of `scipy.optimize.least_squares`, `max_nfev` is the number of function evaluations before the program exits :

> max_nfev : None or int, optional
>       Maximum number of function evaluations before the termination.
>       If None (default), the value is chosen automatically:

Again, according to the help, there is no MaxIterations argument but you can define the tolerance in f (`ftol`) that is the function you want to minimize or x (`xtol`) the solution, before exiting the code.

You can also use `scipy.optimize.minimize()`. In it, you can define a `maxiter` argument which will be in the `options` dictionary.
If you do so, beware that the function you want to minimize must be your cost function, meaning that you will have to *code* your least square function.

I hope it will be clear and useful to you

Comment: Hello Nethaniel. let me rephrase, the max_nfev (scipy) is equivalent to MaxFunctionEvaluations (matlab), they both count for the function evaluations only. is there a limit for the number of jacobian calculations? as there in matlab (MaxIterations)?

Comment: Well I don't think there is such a limit available, at least I can't find it